# How to disk copy with unreadable sectors?

Tags: linux, partition, dd, disk-image

I want to clone a whole disk bytewise, something like

```
dd if=/dev/$SRC of=/dev/$DST bs=65536 count=$count
```

There are better tools for the job, which understand the file system (Windows) and work faster (I don't care), but they fail because of unreadable sectors on the old source disk.

There's actually a single invalid block I have to skip. So I thought about using `dd` multiple times like

```
dd if=/dev/$SRC of=/dev/$DST bs=65536 count=...
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/$DST bs=65536 count=... skip=... seek=...
dd if=/dev/$SRC of=/dev/$DST bs=65536 count=... skip=... seek=...
```

with replacing the broken sector data by zeros. Is this a valid approach? I found this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33714/5116) which confuses me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not reinvent the wheel. Use [`ddrescue`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/).

> GNU ddrescue is a data recovery tool. It copies data from one file or block device (hard disc, cdrom, etc) to another, trying to rescue the good parts first in case of read errors.

[Do not trust](https://superuser.com/a/1075837/432690) `dd conv=sync,noerror`, unless you really know how it works.