# How to resolve dd error reading?

Tags: hard-disk, dd, badblocks, e2fsck

I have dd error reading

```
# sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=backup.img bs=4M status=progress
16478679040 bytes (16 GB, 15 GiB) copied, 154 s, 107 MB/s
dd: error reading '/dev/sda1': Input/output error
3928+1 records in
3928+1 records out
16478679040 bytes (16 GB, 15 GiB) copied, 156.816 s, 105 MB/s
```

I thought this probably means disk has bad blocks. I ran

```
# e2fsck -cfpv -C 0 /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: Updating bad block inode.

      700895 inodes used (3.66%, out of 19144704)
        2596 non-contiguous files (0.4%)
        1226 non-contiguous directories (0.2%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
             Extent depth histogram: 638434/974/3
     9995951 blocks used (13.05%, out of 76571648)
           1 bad block
           3 large files

      515535 regular files
      117354 directories
          57 character device files
          26 block device files
           0 fifos
         284 links
       67853 symbolic links (61332 fast symbolic links)
          61 sockets
------------
      701170 files
```

It apparently fixed not what important for `dd`. How to fix what is needed?

Comment: Check for ddrescu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disk copy with unreadable sectors?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/572246/how-to-disk-copy-with-unreadable-sectors)

Comment: Your `dd` command copies the block device’s contents. It doesn’t know or care about the file system, so the bad block inode there is of no use to it.