# Creating a compressed image of an exFAT USB drive using dd

Tags: command-line, dd, compression, disk-image, exfat

My system is running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I plug a USB drive into that system. That USB drive (/dev/sdb) contains an Ubuntu installation, mostly in an ext4 partition (/dev/sdb3). That installation fills about 25GB of drive space.

With /dev/sdb3 unmounted, I use `sudo zerofree -v /dev/sdb3` to zero free space on that USB drive. Then I use the following command to create a compressed image:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb bs=16M conv=sync,noerror | pv | sudo pigz -c > /media/TargetDrive/UbuntuImage.dd.gz
```

This seems effective. The resulting .gz file weighs only 12GB.

Now I remove that USB drive (/dev/sdb) and replace it with a USB drive containing a [YUMI exFAT](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) installation.

When I seek information on this /dev/sdb drive using GParted, I get a warning - "Unable to read the contents of this file system!" - and an indication that `exfatprogs` is required for exfat file system support. I install `exfatprogs` and restart GParted. That eliminates that warning.

This YUMI exFAT installation fills 43GB on the USB drive. I understand that `zerofree` and Microsoft's `sdelete -z E:` don't zerofill on exFAT, so I follow [advice](https://superuser.com/a/1097391/124687) that seems to recommend the following:

```
sudo mount -o rw /dev/sdbX /mnt
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/zero_file bs=32M
sudo sync
sudo rm /mnt/zero_file
sudo umount /dev/sdbX
```

Those commands duly produce and then remove a zero_file whose size does appear to fill empty space. (I saw but did not try this alternative, which was less clear to me: `cat > /dev/sdbX/zeros < /dev/zero ; sync ; rm /dev/sdbX/zeros`.)

Then I run substantially the `dd` command shown above. This time, `dd` and `pigz` do not achieve comparable compression. The 43GB exFAT installation is saved in an image file of 42GB.

Granted, the exFAT drive's contents are produced by Windows. But experience with Windows drive imaging software indicates that I should expect substantial compression.

My question: can the `dd` command be improved to yield better compression for this exFAT drive?

Note: I seem to have obtained similarly poor compression with an NTFS USB drive, but did not document each step in that case.

Comment: "can the `dd` command be improved to yield better compression […]?" – `dd` has nothing to do with compression. Compression depends on the entropy of the data and on `pigz`. By writing zeros you have reduced the entropy without touching useful data. What you can do is to replace `pigz` with something better. Your `dd` is responsible for [corrupting data maybe](https://superuser.com/a/1075837). [Do not use it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121888). `sudo pv /dev/sdb | …` will read healthy `/dev/sdb` just fine. If you expect errors, [use `ddrescue`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/572247).

Comment: Cross-posted: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1477273/zeroing-to-achieve-compact-dd-image-of-ntfs-flash-drive

Comment: I would recommend Clonezilla for this purpose. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958242/fastest-way-to-copy-hdd/958248#958248).

Comment: @sudodus : the Clonezilla suggestion is worthy but not ideal for me. I have commented and upvoted it.

@KamilMaciorowski : sorry, I thought it was obvious that I was referring to the entire command beginning with `dd`. Comments on your link re: possible data corruption make the point: `dd` has been extensively researched and applied over decades. Being less thoroughly tested does not make an alternative superior. The conclusion appears to be simply that my `dd` command should use `iflag=fullblock`. My limited research suggests that `pigz` is superior - but I welcome a link to the contrary.

Comment: Possible correction re `iflag=fullblock` : further reading suggests that may be advisable only when using `count`. Anyway, I do welcome advice specific to the command shown above. I'm not using `dd` in the relatively abstruse contexts discussed in those other posts.

Comment: @RayWoodcock, Making a dd image, I don't think you can improve the compression much by replacing `pigz` with some other tool (I use `xz` for similar purposes.) and you have already zeroized the unused data blocks (free space of the file system). But if the file system is encrypted, zeroizing and compression will not help much. If you backup the data on the file level when the file system is decrypted and mounted, it corresponds to skipping unused data blocks also when the file system is encrypted. I would use `rsync` or some dedicated backup tool for file level operations.

Answer (score 2):

(This didn't fit in a comment, so trying here.)

Excellent question. Unfortunately I'm not sure - that process is pretty much exactly what I would do. You don't say how big your "zeros" file is. If it's really small there just isn't any space available on the drive. The other alternative is that these disks are somehow automatically encrypted, in which case there won't be any actual zeroes written.

Another option, since you mentioned partitions, is that the partition you're writing to is small and there's a bunch of free space that you can't access but which you capture when you image the entire device. If that's the case, you either need to create a new filesystem that uses the rest of the space on the drive that you can write zeros to, OR write zeroes to the entire device (e.g, `/dev/sdb`, but be careful!) *before* you put the YUMI/etc. image on top of it.

Regarding this comment:

> `cat > /dev/sdbX/zeros < /dev/zero ; sync ; rm /dev/sdbX/zeros`

That doesn't work. `/dev/sdb` is the entire device; `/dev/sdbX` is a partition on a device; `/dev/sdb/whatever` doesn't exist. The partition (or alternately, full device) needs a mounted filesystem in order to hold a file called `zeros`. That aside, the command is the same as `cat /dev/zero > /path/to/zeros` if that's clearer to you.

I would also suggest using `bzip2` or `xz` in your pipeline if you want better compression. Those are both widely supported compression formats. The YUMI install image is probably already in a disk image that gets uncompressed when it boots so you'll get very little additional compression from imaging it.

Comment: I appreciate the correction re `cat`. My limited reading suggested that xz and bzip2 took dramatically longer for marginally improved compression. See e.g., https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/3cnn54/just_a_reminder_on_multi_core_systems_use_pigz/

Regarding the YUMI compression, I'm not sure. YUMI doesn't seem to decompress anything, unlike Rufus. See https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2023/09/25/ubuntu-bootable-iso/#resu

Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Sorry, @RayWoodcock; I assumed YUMI was a distro until I skimmed your blog. Most "live distros" (that you run from a USB drive) are comprised of a Linux kernel and an initrd file that is an entire filesystem compressed into a single file (like what it sounds like you are trying to do, or what /dev/sdbX is). So compressing a system like this is near-fruitless. I understand 'xz' is a more modern p7zip (they are both LZMA) and you described generating a .xz file. Time or space is a tradeoff you have to choose. But I think I answered your main question. Let me know what you tried that didn't work.

Comment: '@rand'Chris : that seems to be the case with YUMI too. A brief attempt to compress its contents using WinRAR reaches similar results: evidently compressed ISOs, forming most of its contents, being compressed by only 10-15%.